# Floating origin and visual effect graph in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, floating-point, particles, visual-effects

I am sure that everybody knows about this script, http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Floating_Origin, that fixes problems with floating origin easily.

The problem is that the script is outdated and does not move the particle effects created by visual effect graph.

I was trying to rewrite it but I cant seem to make an array to store all the particles, like with the previous one, thus I can't continue from there.

Here is my code:

```c#
// Based on the Unity Wiki FloatingOrigin script by Peter Stirling
// URL: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Floating_Origin

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.VFX;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.VFX;

public class FloatingOrigin : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Point of reference from which to check the distance to origin.")]
    public Transform ReferenceObject = null;

    [Tooltip("Distance from the origin the reference object must be in order to trigger an origin shift.")]
    public float Threshold = 5000f;

    [Header("Options")]
    [Tooltip("When true, origin shifts are considered only from the horizontal distance to orign.")]
    public bool Use2DDistance = false;

    [Tooltip("When true, updates ALL open scenes. When false, updates only the active scene.")]
    public bool UpdateAllScenes = true;

    [Tooltip("Should ParticleSystems be moved with an origin shift.")]
    public bool UpdateParticles = true;

    [Tooltip("Should TrailRenderers be moved with an origin shift.")]
    public bool UpdateTrailRenderers = true;

    [Tooltip("Should LineRenderers be moved with an origin shift.")]
    public bool UpdateLineRenderers = true;

    private ParticleSystem.Particle[] parts = null;

    VisualEffect[] visualEffect = null;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (ReferenceObject == null)
            return;

        Vector3 referencePosition = ReferenceObject.position;

        if (Use2DDistance)
            referencePosition.y = 0f;

        if (referencePosition.magnitude > Threshold)
        {
            MoveRootTransforms(referencePosition);

            if (UpdateParticles)
                MoveParticles(referencePosition);

            if (UpdateTrailRenderers)
                MoveTrailRenderers(referencePosition);

            if (UpdateLineRenderers)
                MoveLineRenderers(referencePosition);
        }
    }

    private void MoveRootTransforms(Vector3 offset)
    {
        if (UpdateAllScenes)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < SceneManager.sceneCount; z++)
            {
                foreach (GameObject g in SceneManager.GetSceneAt(z).GetRootGameObjects())
                    g.transform.position -= offset;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (GameObject g in SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects())
                g.transform.position -= offset;
        }
    }

    private void MoveTrailRenderers(Vector3 offset)
    {
        var trails = FindObjectsOfType<TrailRenderer>() as TrailRenderer[];
        foreach (var trail in trails)
        {
            Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[trail.positionCount];

            int positionCount = trail.GetPositions(positions);
            for (int i = 0; i < positionCount; ++i)
                positions[i] -= offset;

            trail.SetPositions(positions);
        }
    }

    private void MoveLineRenderers(Vector3 offset)
    {
        var lines = FindObjectsOfType<LineRenderer>() as LineRenderer[];
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[line.positionCount];

            int positionCount = line.GetPositions(positions);
            for (int i = 0; i < positionCount; ++i)
                positions[i] -= offset;

            line.SetPositions(positions);
        }
    }

    private void MoveParticles(Vector3 offset)
    {
        var particles = FindObjectsOfType<ParticleSystem>() as ParticleSystem[];
        foreach (ParticleSystem system in particles)
        {
            if (system.main.simulationSpace != ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.World)
                continue;

            int particlesNeeded = system.main.maxParticles;

            if (particlesNeeded <= 0)
                continue;

            bool wasPaused = system.isPaused;
            bool wasPlaying = system.isPlaying;

            if (!wasPaused)
                system.Pause();

            // ensure a sufficiently large array in which to store the particles
            if (parts == null || parts.Length < particlesNeeded)
            {
                parts = new ParticleSystem.Particle[particlesNeeded];
            }

            // now get the particles
            int num = system.GetParticles(parts);

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                parts[i].position -= offset;
            }

            system.SetParticles(parts, num);

            if (wasPlaying)
                system.Play();
        }
        
        var particles2 = FindObjectsOfType<VisualEffect>() as VisualEffect[];
        foreach (VisualEffect system in particles2)
        {
            int particlesNeeded = system.aliveParticleCount;

            if (particlesNeeded <= 0)
                continue;

            bool wasPaused = !system.isActiveAndEnabled;
            bool wasPlaying = system.isActiveAndEnabled;

            if (!wasPaused)
                system.Stop();
            // ensure a sufficiently large array in which to store the particles
            if (visualEffect == null || visualEffect.Length < particlesNeeded)
            {
                visualEffect = new VisualEffect().visualEffectAsset[particlesNeeded];
            }

            // now get the particles
            int num = system.GetParticles(parts);

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                parts[i].position -= offset;
            }

            system.SetParticles(parts, num);

            if (wasPlaying)
                system.Play();
            
        }
    } 
}
```

On the line(this is a wrong line and everything below it too)

```c#
visualEffect = new VisualEffect().visualEffectAsset[particlesNeeded];
```

, I need to create a similar array to the line (correct one, but for the old particle system)

```c#
parts = new ParticleSystem.Particle[particlesNeeded];
```

that creates array full of particles (but with VisualEffect class).

If I can fix this one, there should not be any problem with the rest.
I think that solving this problem will help literally thousands of people now and in the future, since limitation for floating origin in unity are horrible and majority of people working in unity will need floating origin for their game worlds, with VFX graph particles.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a general note: `I am sure that everybody knows about this script, http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Floating_Origin, that fixes problems with floating origin easily.` .. errr nope .. never heard of it before and never even heard of that "problem" you are talking about before ;) .. a bit unclear what you are trying to do ... [`VisualEffect.visualEffectAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Experimental.VFX.VisualEffect-visualEffectAsset.html) is no array so you can't just treat it as one

Comment: Are you maybe trying to create an array of [`Experimental.VFX.VisualEffectAsset[]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Experimental.VFX.VisualEffectAsset.html) instead? or an array of `VisualEffect[]` so that each of them holds its own `visualEffectAsset`? Note in particular that `VisualEffect` is of type `Behaviour` -> **You may not create instances using the `new` keyword!** A `Behaviour` can not live without being attached to a `GameObject` so either instantiated via `Instantiate`, `AddComponent` or `new GameObject("", typeof(XY))`

Comment: Wow, you have never head about Floating point precision error ? I mean, if you move 5000 units in unity, you will experience glitches right away. Ofc, if you are making small games in scale then you never needed to know about it. 

Anyhow, First I need to create an array large enough to store all of the particles, then I need to access them. Once I have every single particle, I can move it by an offset, just like the script does for old particle system.
I am kind of lost because the functions for the new GPU particle system has different methods and properties.

Comment: Dude, ofcourse I know what a floating point issue is ... but I never heard `floating origin` before or what exactly that script is good for

Answer (score 0):

My question has been answered here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/floating-origin-and-visual-effect-graph.962646/#post-6270837